# Read file from google drive in chunks and insert each chunk to database before moving to the next one using python

Tags: python, pandas, google-drive-api, file-handling

So I have this function to read files in google drive in pandas dataframe

```
    def file_download(file_id, file_name, service, tempdir):
        """Function to download files from google drive

        Args:
            file_id (str): Id of the file
            file_name (str): Name of the file
            service (str): Service for google drive
            tempdir (str): Path to temp directory
        """
        request = service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
        fh = io.BytesIO()

        # Initialise a downloader object to download the file
        downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
        done = False

        try:
            # Download the data in chunks
            while not done:
                status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
                logger.info(status)

            fh.seek(0)
            df_insert = pd.read_csv(fh)

            logger.info(f"File {file_name} Downloaded")
            # Return df_insert if file Downloaded successfully
            return df_insert
        except Exception as exc:
            # Return False if something went wrong
            logger.error(f"Download failed for file {file_name}")
            raise exc
```

Issue here is even though `downloader.next_chunk()` is getting files in chunk and saving it in `fh`, the total size of file is too big to be saved in memory. Is there a away that I can create a dataframe from each chunk and insert it to database before moving to the next one?

I'm inserting to database using the below after returning the complete dataframe from the above function

```
                df.to_sql(
                    table_name,
                    snowflake_client.connection,
                    if_exists="append",
                    index=False,
                    chunksize=100000,
                    method=sfpd.pd_writer,
                )
```